# When testing with Cypress.io how to programmatically log in using nuxt.js and nuxt-auth

Tags: nuxt.js, cypress

Testing with Cypress.io I would like to trigger a "stubbed" log in on my Nuxt app.

I have tried stubbing the login and user-details XHR calls that the nuxt-auth module fires.

I've used a custom plugin to expose the Nuxt app's context to Cypress. *Seemed successful*.

/plugins/cypress.js

```js
const isCypress = typeof window.Cypress !== 'undefined'
export default context => {
  if (isCypress) {
    window.nuxtApp = context
  }
}
```

Within a Cypress spec file I've called nuxt-auth's `$auth.loginWith('local', {…})` which appears to set the Vuex `$state.loggedIn` to `true` and sets the user object with the contents of my fixture file.

Example of my Cypress login command

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  // Use as cy.login()
  cy.server()
  cy.fixture('userLogin').as('userLoginJson')
  cy.fixture('userDetails').as('userDetailsJson')
  cy.route({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/auth/login',
    response: '@userLoginJson'
  }).as('postLogin')
  cy.route({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/user/details',
    response: '@userDetailsJson'
  })
  cy.visit('/')
  cy.window().should('have.property', 'nuxtApp') // is TRUE
  cy.window().then(window => {
    console.log('nuxtApp', window.nuxtApp) // Nuxt context visible in console
    window.nuxtApp.$auth
      .loginWith('local', {
        data: {
          email: 'anything',
          password: 'anything',
          remember_me: true
        }
      })
      .then(response => response)
  })
  cy.visit('/user') // Middleware denies this route. Consistent with being logged out.
})
```

I would like the app to act like it's logged in but middleware continues to deny access to logged in routes and any `v-if="$auth.loggedIn"` within components render as logged out.

/middleware/authenticated.js

```js
export default ({ store, redirect }) => {
  // If the user is not authenticated
  if (!store.state.auth.loggedIn) {
    return redirect('/login')
  }
}
```

My best guess is that Nuxt's server side rendering is getting in the way …but it could be anything ‍♂️.

Thanks

Some inspiration from:

- https://www.cypress.io/blog/2017/11/28/testing-vue-web-application-with-vuex-data-store-and-rest-backend/

Answer (score 2):

I think I was able to get this working. I'm switching from SPA to Universal, so I had to add an extra check to see if I was in the client or not in the plugin:

```
const isCypress = process.client && typeof window.Cypress !== 'undefined'

export default context => {
  if (isCypress) {
    window.nuxtApp = context
  }
}
```

Then my test looks like this:

```
it('displays a list of objective types', () => {
    cy.visit('/admin/objective_types')
    cy.window()
      .then(window => {
        window.nuxtApp.$auth.loginWith('local', {
          data: {
            user: {
              email: 'admin@pyx.com',
              password: 'password'
            }
          }
        }).then(cy.contains('td.title', 'Department'))
      })

  })
```

Comment: Thanks @emptywalls! I'll try it. I was under the impression that's what adding `ssr: false` to the nuxt.config.js plugins list was supposed to be for. Do you have that in addition to this change?

Answer (score 1):

You can also perform a login operation before testing by adding a command.

*cypress/support/command.js*

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("login", user => {
    cy.request("POST", `${apiUrl}/auth/login`, user)
        .its("body.data.access_token")
        .should("exist")
        .then(token =>
            localStorage.setItem("auth._token.local", `Bearer ${token}`)
        );
});
```

simple e2e test:

```js
describe("CART WHEN USER IS AUTHORIZED", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.login();

        cy.get("[cart-button]").click();

        cy.get(".event").as("event");
        cy.get("[button-delete]")
            .first()
            .as("delete");
    });
});
```

Comment: You are not passing a user object into your beforeEach login call. Are you supposed to provide parameters?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a plugin, here is mine using laravel Sanctrum

```js
  Cypress.Commands.add("login", (email, password) => {
  cy.intercept("GET", "api/sanctum/csrf-cookie").as("csrfCookie");

  cy.intercept("POST", "/api/login", {
    fixture: "auth/user-login.json",
  }).as("userLogin");

  cy.fixture("auth/user-info.json").then((user) => {
    user.email = email;
    cy.intercept("GET", "/api/user", user).as("userInfo");
  });

  cy.window()
    .its("$nuxt")
    .then((nuxt) => {
      nuxt.$auth.loginWith("laravelSanctum", {
        data: {
          email: email,
          password: password,
          //   remember_me: true,
        },
      });
      cy.wait("@userInfo");
    });
```